# Exporting data to excel with pivot table - without server access

Tags: angularjs, excel, sharepoint, export, pivot

I have been looking around for a day or two and I have a feeling the answer will be a simple 'no' to my question, but it does worth a try:

Is it possible to export data (JSON) to an excel file (can be xls, xml, xlsx or whatever that is capable of displaying pivot tables) which will then render and display functions and pivot tables *without having access to the server side*?

The circumstances are the following: a SharePoint site contains all the data in lists which is then gathered and displayed by using AngularJS. I did found [PivotTableJS](http://pivottable.js.org), [ALASQL](https://github.com/agershun/alasql), [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js) and such libraries/addons but couldn't make it work. Is it even possible or my hunch is right that it will not work with no server access?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, i.e. you want to export a file from your angular app that contains the data in the app, and of a format that excel can open. When it does open in excel a pivot table is immediately available to the user to pivot the data also in the file.

The only way I can see to do this would be to take an existing excel file with a pivot table already set up in it, and then simply replace the data in the relevant sheets that the pivot references. The save that file to the client's machine when requested. [This](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs) project may help with inserting the data in the Angular App, but I've never used it. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, but you did understand it correctly! Already tried ExcelJS with no success, but I like the approach you propose. I'll try it and get back to you with the result tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: well, it did not actually work (could never load data to any pre-set pivot table), although pointed our project to other directions so I'll get back on topic in a few days/weeks and let you and others know whether it is possible or not

Comment: Real remote ideas. 1.  What if the data is in say "Sheet1", then create pivot table from there in "Sheet2". Via Excel JS, update data in sheet1, then trigger a refresh on the PivotTable either via ExcelJS, or via a internal macro/interop code when it is loaded by Excel. This assumes the data remains same shape. 2. Load data to page with ExcelJS, add some syntax to a cell somewhere to describe data. Use metadata from cell in  a startup macro/interop code to build the pivot on load. Awful but an idea..